# acts_as_votable button not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

issue as above, unable to get "like" button working, posted changes as follows. Thank you in advance. I have modified the routes, models views, controllers as follows.

Acts as Votable Migration

```
class ActsAsVotableMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up
create_table :votes do |t|

  t.references :votable, :polymorphic => true
  t.references :voter, :polymorphic => true

  t.boolean :vote_flag
  t.string :vote_scope

  t.timestamps
 end

add_index :votes, [:votable_id, :votable_type]
add_index :votes, [:voter_id, :voter_type]
add_index :votes, [:voter_id, :voter_type, :vote_scope]
add_index :votes, [:votable_id, :votable_type, :vote_scope]
end

def self.down
drop_table :votes
 end
end
```

Routes=

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts do
  member do
  post :like
  end
resources :comments
end
end
```

Models

```
(User)has_many :posts
(Post)has_many :comments
(Post)belongs_to :user
(Comment)belongs_to :post
```

Controller(posts)

```
def like
@post= Post.find(params[:id])
@post.liked_by current_user
redirect_to :back
flash[:notice]="Liked!" 
end
```

Index(posts)

```
  <%= link_to  like_user_post_path(post.user,post), :method => :post ,:class =>""  do%>
        <span class="btn btn-primary editlike">
        <%=post.likes.size %>
<i class="icon-heart ">
</i></span><%end %>
```

Comment: what is the error message dumped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make nice voting system you can use these gems

https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up

https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system

I am using thumbs_up on my app and its working great

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a go, will let you know how it works out